# How to do a covariant generic return type in a method?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that I want to have a method that returns an instance of the implementing class, my current implementation is this:

```
interface SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<any>> {
  returnSelf(): T; 
}

class SubClass implements SuperClass<SubClass> {
  public returnSelf(): SubClass {
    return this;
  }
}

const subclass: SubClass = new SubClass().returnSelf();
```

However, this uses the `any` type, which I know is supposed to be avoided at all costs. My question is, is this typesafe? I can't think of any case in which it wouldn't be, but I would like to rather use the safer `unknown` type, however that doesn't compile. Why? Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` as a type.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types

```
interface SuperClass {
  returnSelf(): this;
}

class SubClass implements SuperClass {
  public returnSelf(): this {
    return this;
  }
}

const subclass: SubClass = new SubClass().returnSelf();
```

Comment: Really good! Actually much easier to understand than what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can use recursive constraint:

```js
// recursive
interface SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<T>> {
  returnSelf(): T;
}

class SubClass implements SuperClass<SubClass> {
  public returnSelf(): SubClass {
    return this;
  }
}

const subclass = new SubClass().returnSelf()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcAO0DCAbOAZ0IB4AVZCAD0hABNC0tcDjyA%20d5AbwChlkUCGHRQQqCHhgAKAJQAuZGQDcvAL69eCVowwAjfEUbAAtpjwQTEcLuZRDbfQ8Jc%20AzOj15gCQcNHikjIKTAY6PPwCfiJiyGAAFsCEqgIaGloA9iCEYMiEntpGyAC8yCAQAO6hznIAdEIxgVJyQA)